# Android: How do I prevent the soft keyboard from pushing my view up?

Tags: android, layout, keyboard, view

I have a vertical sliding drawer at the bottom of my app. When the soft keyboard opens, it pushes the tab for the drawer up, so it sits atop the keyboard. I actually want it to remain at the bottom of the screen, becoming hidden when the keyboard is shown.

Anyone else run into this issue? Know how to fix it?

Comment: hi, I am having same problem which flag you have used in manifest file, can you plz help me with that

Comment: This question is duplicated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516216/how-to-avoid-soft-keyboard-pushing-up-my-layout

Answer (score 785, accepted):

You can simply switch your Activity's `windowSoftInputMode`flag to `adjustPan` in your `AndroidMainfest.xml` file inside your activity tag.

Check the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) for more info.

```
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
</activity>
```

If your container is not changing size, then you likely have the height set to "match parent". If possible, set the parent to "Wrap Content", or a constraint layout with constraingts to top and bottom of parent.

The parent container will shrink to fit the available space, so it is likely that your content should be inside of a scolling view to prevent (depending on the phone manufacturer and the layout choosen...)

1. Content being smashed together
2. Content hanging off the screen
3. Content being inacccessable due to it being underneath the keyboard

even if the layout it is in is a relative or constraint layout, the content could exhibit problems 1-3.

Comment: I don't want the view to pan, I want it to remain static where it is, and just have the keyboard cover up whatever it's going to cover up.

Comment: By panning it's meant that view will be scrolled to make visible that view which you're typing to. In other words if just appeared keyboard didn't cover up focused view it will remain static.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. made the windowSoftInputMode flag to "adjustPan" in manifeast file.but not working . how to solve it

Comment: Doesn't help in my case of having a row of buttons on the bottom of the screen and a ScrollView above them. The buttons get pushed up no matter what value is in windowSoftInputMode.

Comment: @ArtemRussakovskii have you found a solution to this? I still have the problem.

Comment: Working great, but you view layout must be != LinearLayout, I didn't check other layouts, I wrap my view into RelativeLayout and now works

Comment: I found that this general method works as long as your activity is not full screen

Comment: This actually didn't work for mi adjustResize ended up working after taking a look at the layout and seeing that there was a useless relative layout in there.

Comment: not working in a fragment. How to do it in fragment?

Comment: @AlexanderOleynikov i am facing problem similar this. help me to solve it.

Comment: I've used softkeyboard in my fragment but doing this in parent activity solved the problem.

Comment: Please help to avoid scroll up of `Toolbar` when keyboard is shown. Just using `adjustPan` doesn't work for me.

Comment: I am writing android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" inside my application tag to prevent layout changes when keyboard opens up, but it didnot work. can you tell me if there is a way to prevent keyboard from changing UI for entire app?

Comment: Praise the lord I'm so happy. I've been searching up and reading up on this and it seemed like I had to make a whole new activity and then I'd need a landscape version too and need to copy over all my xml, or I'd have to hide my buttons and there's no setting a class so I'd have to hide all 18 of them in a function or just put them in a container but it's a constraint layout so they're all relative to each other and I can't easily do that without messing everything up, and either way I'd have to figure out the event for setting them back up like on search or keyboard close... PRAISE

Answer (score 240):

None of the answers worked for me, but this did the trick, add this attribute to the `activity` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
     ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"> 
</activity>
```

Comment: This makes keyboard appear overlaying content, without making layout to recalculate it's height.

Comment: This solves the issue of the keyboard pushing the content up though which is what I and the OP wanted to achieve.

Comment: borrowing from @Dom you can use `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);` to set this value programmatically

Comment: This one does work for me, unlike other answers (jelly bean 4.1)

Comment: Perfect! It is also working in my case. I am showing a dialog that has a edittext inside. As soon as dialog opens, keyboard also was appearing. I have tried "adjustPan", but it blocked keyboard appearing feature. So, "adjustNothing" worked better in my case.

Comment: not working in a fragment. How to do it in fragment? I tried getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHI‌​NG); this also not working.

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar if you'd like to use it in `fragment`, use it like this `getActivity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT‌​_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHI‌‌​​NG);`
`getActivity` will associate that particular `fragment` with its `activity`

Comment: This one worked for me. If you have a dialog at the front of the activity.

Comment: This worked for me rather than `adjustResize`. My Activity has a child viewpager which has 3 child fragments. I needed to combine `statehidden` to prevent keyboard from popping up too. Worked like a charm

Comment: It's working, but how i can scroll view when kayboard is attached? This is cover my buttons on bottom side of layout

Answer (score 96):

In my case, the reason the buttons got pushed up was because the view above them was a `ScrollView`, and it got collapsed with the buttons pushed up above the keyboard no matter what value of `android:windowSoftInputMode` I was setting.

I was able to avoid my bottom row of buttons getting pushed up by the soft keyboard by setting `android:isScrollContainer="false"` on the `ScrollView` that sits above the buttons.

Comment: But in this case the soft keyboard covers part of the screen and there's no way to scroll down.
Looks like there is only one way to prevent bottom panel to show up at the top of the keyboard - hiding it when keyboard is open...

Comment: this is it! This setting is in my opinion very interesting to remark, as is the only way I have found to achieve the effects of "adjustNothing" missing property!

Comment: FYI to everyone, this also applies to elements that contain scrolling behavior, such as `listview`

Comment: Just to add a note, for `WebViews` you'll also need to add  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> ` besides `android:isScrollContainer="false"`

Answer (score 91):

You can try to add this attribute dynamically, by putting the following code in the `onCreate` method of your activity:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

This worked for me, but that:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

didnt.

Comment: Did you added the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: No, as it didnt really make any difference for me. The first line of code did the job. :) @HabeebPerwad

Comment: I added the seconds line in AndoidManifest.xml file. I think after that only it worked. so just asked.

Comment: @Dom, how to use "`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);`" in a fragment?

Comment: @TusharGogna I only used in classes where there were both Activity and Fragment class, so I used this method in onCreate() method of the Activity class. If I find out how to do that in fragment, I´ll let you know.

Comment: Finally! This works! I had a controller (extends from `FragmentActivity`) and some views attached to it (the views extend from `RelativeLayout`). So in the troublesome view i did `controller.getWindow()...` like you said. Works

Comment: Boom, this did it for me. I also tried the windowSoftInputmode but it wasnt available an available autocomplete option activity file, so I added it into onCreate and success. Thanks :)

Answer (score 47):

These answers here didn't help me. So I tried this:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

This worked like a charm,  Now the header of my app doesn't disappear. Its smoother.

Comment: This nearly works perfectly for me. The only problem is that the keyboard's suggestion bar/row still hides my layout. Did you face such an issue?

Comment: For those who may face similar issue, it probably was due to `TabLayout`. The problem was gone once I set its visibility to `View.GONE`. It might be time to redesign my layout.

Comment: This one works without overlap the button at the bottom of my nested scroll view. The "adjustPan" however overlap the bottom button

Answer (score 14):

To do this programatically in a fragment you can use following code

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Place this in onResume()

Answer (score 14):

This one worked for me

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
```

Answer (score 11):

Just a single line to be added...

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"` in required activity of your `manifest file`.

I just got solved :) :)

Answer (score 11):

For future readers.

*I wanted specific control over this issue, so this is what I did:*

From a fragment or activity, **hide your other views** (that aren't needed while the keyboard is up), **then restore them** to solve this problem:

```
            rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    Rect r = new Rect();
                    rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                    int heightDiff = rootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);

                    if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
                    //ok now we know the keyboard is up...
                        view_one.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        view_two.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }else{
                    //ok now we know the keyboard is down...
                        view_one.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        view_two.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: @Skynet You're absolutely right! This was a custom solution that I used for my own problem.

Comment: Hey, this was brilliant. However, the instance the keyboard is closed, there is a short period (milliseconds) where the view is switched to visible. So instead of setting the visibility directly, I used `view.post(Runnable runnable)` and set the visibility from there. It turned out great for me

Comment: @Andrew I switched to Flutter and couldn't be happier, the code is much cleaner too

Comment: Yeah, this will be my last android project for ever. After that I will switch to iOS or just stop programming apps at all. This is hideous.

Comment: @Andrew Adobe XD has an export to Flutter function, check it out... might make your life easier

Answer (score 9):

So far the answers didn't help me as I have a button and a textInput field (side by side) below the textView which kept getting hidden by the keyboard, but this has solved my issue:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 9):

For xamarin users add this code to Activity attribute of the MainActivity class,

```
WindowSoftInputMode =Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustNothing
```

or you can add this code `Window.SetSoftInputMode(Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustNothing)` to the OnCreate method of MainActivity class.

Answer (score 8):

This was the best which worked for me

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

Try it!

Answer (score 7):

Add following code to the 'activity' of Manifest file.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: This works well. However, just to advice, it doesn´t work well when you use percent. Because it readjust some elements. 
So, if you have Constraints elements with percent you will have problem. Use wrap_content instead and it will works very well.

Answer (score 7):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing"
```

This code works.

Comment: I think android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" should also work.

Answer (score 6):

Well i have watched these answers but in my case i fell into the same issue and got refuge through a very handy and easiest solution that involves putting a very small innocent attribute in your Scrollview tag residing in your xml file. That is

```
android:isScrollContainer="false"
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

This one is working for me.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved my issue by adding

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

In manifest file add.

and making the Recyclerviews constraint  isScrollContainer to false .

```
android:isScrollContainer="false"
```

Answer (score 2):

For Scroll View:

if after adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"` in your Android Manifest and still does not work.

It may be affected because when the keyboard appears, it will be into a scroll view and if your button/any objects  is not in your scroll view then the objects will follow the keyboard and move its position.

Check out your xml where your button is and make sure it is under your scroll View bracket and not out of it.

Hope this helps out. :D

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I needed the keyboard to stay hidden and just after the click of the button my layout needs to be adjusted, so I just added this command in the manifest and it got super right.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 2):

When you want to hide view when open keyboard.

Add this into your Activity in manifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 2):

None of them worked for me, try this one

```
 private void scrollingWhileKeyboard() {
    drawerlayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            Rect r = new Rect();
            try {
                drawerlayout.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                int screenHeight = drawerlayout.getRootView().getHeight();
                int keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom;
                if (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15) {
                    tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {

            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling for a while with this problem. Some of the solutions worked however some of my views where still being pushed up while others weren't... So it didn't completely solve my problem. In the end, what did the job was adding the following line of code to my manifest in the activity tag...

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

The activity's main window will not resize to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window will be automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

This might be a better solution for what you desired.

Answer (score 1):

This code may help you. Use it in your `oncreate` method.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Comment: I tried this but I am having issues where the view cuts off a bit of the bottom part of the view and pushes the view to overlay the time above? Any ideas on what layout changes or what is needed? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39909897/how-to-push-up-the-whole-view-when-a-keyboard-comes-up-what-layout-changes-need

Answer (score 1):

Include in your manifest file under activity which you want to display .But make sure not using Full screen Activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 1):

@manifest in your activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of solving this problem.
Go to the AndroidManifist.xml, and in the name of your activity, add this line

```
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

As in the below code, I have added to the Register Activity.

```
 <activity android:name=".Register"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

In the second way, go to your activity, and in your onCreate method, add this code.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using transparent status bar so nothing worked for me. Instead of transparent statusbar hiding the status bar worked for me

```
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

and added this for activity in manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case - soft keyboard moving up the BACKGROUND image - none of the answers published here worked. However I found a solution.

Set the background image for the whole screen (activity):

- Create a style with your background:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_image</item>
</style>
```

- Apply the theme on the activity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

In the end, the background image will remain fixed in place