# How to keep some of the components fixed when the soft keyboard comes in?

Tags: android, layout

My application is a chat application, and its UI is:

Header of the app
List View
Chat message, input box, and send button

But the problem is when I click the edit text, the soft keyboard comes and pushes everything up, but I need the header to stay on the screen. I've attached the simplified problem images and UI code [here](http://picasaweb.google.com/tozoysa/Android#). (I can't post multiple links or images in this post because I'm new to Stack Overflow.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:text="Header contents" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" />

    <EditText android:text="" android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/EditText01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Android has this requirement in the default messaging app.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is quite old, but anyhow - one way to fix this is to put everything that comes below the header within a ScrollView.

Example:

```
<!-- Both elements below are children of a parent RelativeLayout -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/custom_action_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="false" >

    <!-- Header goes here. -->
    <!-- This part remains fixed even with the keypad popping up. -->

</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/custom_action_bar"
    android:isScrollContainer="true" >

    <!-- Rest of the UI -->
    <!-- This part scrolls to accommodate the keyboard -->

 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: +1This is the only working solution if you have multiple views, and you need to keep few of them static on a place and let rest of the others get resized or panned.

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` on the activity/application tag of manifest.

Answer (score 1):

The solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up) is the solution. Your fullscreen theme is responsible for Kamil Los not being able to reproduce your issue.

You need to adjust the activity's windowSoftInputMode tag, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).

Try adding the tag "android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"" to the offending activity in your application's manifest.

Answer (score -1):

That is quite strange, because I have created a new project, pasted your layout and the header does not disappear in my case (neither in 2.2 emulator nor 1.6).

Comment: Ok i got the problem, but not solved yet. in my application what i have done is, i have use full screen. thats why keyboard pushing everything, see this project " http://www.freefilehosting.net/chatuilayout "

Comment: Try the solution described here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up

Comment: It doesn't solved my Problem. the problem is if i am in full screen mode and then key board comes and pushing everything up.