# Tabs move upwards on click inside Edittext

Tags: android, tabs

On a screen I have an EditText and 2 tabs on bottom of the page, when I click inside EditText, the tabs shift upwards as soft keypad opens.
How to fix the tab to the bottom of the screen so that they wont move upward when soft keypad is opened.
Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4208067/985143

Answer (score 5):

In your application's manifest file, In current Activity tag put

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: +1 And here is More info:[Android windowSoftInputMode – Resize the application for the soft-keyboard](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2010/10/25/android-windowsoftinputmode/)

Comment: More info look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Answer (score 1):

just put this message

**android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"**

in your Activity menifeast file.