# pop-up keyboard destroys my listView

Tags: android, listview, dialog

So in my ListView I have 4 different views I inflate, and one of them takes user input with a simple  AlertDialog EditText and then saves it to a TextView. The problem I'm running into is when the user clicks on the editText and has the keyboard pop-up for them to type, it switches all my views in my listView. I'm thinking it rearranges them because the keyboard is taking up half the screen... but I honestly have NO idea. This only happens when I test my app on my droid razr. If I test on my nexus 7, I have no problem because the keyboard doesn't take up as much room of the screen.

I'll post a picture from my nexus 7 because I can't take a SS with my razr.

This is pre-keyboard pop-up[image]

This is post-keyboard popup

[image]

They don't look so different since it's on the nexus 7 with a 10 inch screen, but when I test this on my razr....my headers/views all switch around It's like android goes ahead and recycles them. Is there any way to stop this..? To keep the listView views as they are?

Comment: Using a edittext and listview is very volatile :). Since there are only 4 you can use a simple layout. As there is hardly any view reuse which you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line in your AndroidManifest.xml inside your specific activity tag

```
<activity android:name="com.packagename.activities" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"></activity>
```

For more reference please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up)

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

add this in your manifest with the activity

Example

```
    <activity android:name="YourActivity" >
     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|stateUnchanged"
    </activity>
```