# How to prevent sliding a layout when keyboard show up

Tags: android, android-layout

I have written a layout xml and put `EditText` below of `ImageView` and above of a button. When I click the `EditText` for texting, button is coming up and it is showing on `EditText` .How to solve this problem? I have added to manifest  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` . It is still not working. Here is my layout;

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextGunlukIcerik"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:maxLines="7"
    android:overScrollMode="always"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTarih"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:textStyle="normal|italic"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextGunlukIcerik"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonGunlukKaydet"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:text="Kaydet" />
```

Comment: first Show Your layout

Comment: I have put the layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use below code to AndroidManifest file inside  tag like given below

```
 <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" 
           android:name=".MainActivity" >
```

Refer to this question

[Android: How do I prevent the soft keyboard from pushing my view up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up)

Comment: Use LinearLayout then...Problem causes because you are using RelativeLayout & Button is at bottom of parent