# Layout changing when typing

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I got a screen which has an `EditText`. When I click to type in this edit, the whole layout gets fuzzy as it was compressed by the virtual keyboard. It didn't happen to any other screen. Here is an image of what's happening:

[image]

Comment: image you uploaded is not found

Comment: Can you please put xml file code so that i can have better suggestion for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4208067/562840) answer, you can just switch your activity windowSoftInputMode flag to "adjustPan".