# Android: how to avoid soft keyboard pushing up my layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/include_toolbar_actionbar"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/keyline_5"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/keyline_2"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/keyline_2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            style="@style/FlatCardTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TITLE" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/keyline_4"
            android:lines="16"
            android:minLines="4"
            android:maxLines="16"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<include layout="@layout/include_visibility_right_editor" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout "include_visibility_right_editor" must be always at the bottom. Unfortunately, when the soft keyboard appears, all the layout is pushing up...

Thank for your help guys!

Comment: did u try adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing in the activity tag in your manifest?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How do I prevent the soft keyboard from pushing my view up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up)

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up

Answer (score 0):

Use the following property in manifest activity declaration:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

Also check other options according to your requirement