# Leaflet map on android disrupted by appearance of keyboard

Tags: android, mobile, leaflet

I have an android app that uses a webview to point to a website, which contains a leaflet map. On a phone the map is displayed in the top third of the screen. When you click the map a marker is dropped, the map centres on the marker, and a form appears. So far so good. But when you click on the form text area, the android keyboard appears (as it should), but this disrupts the leaflet map. It pushes the tiles and marker upwards off the top of the screen, and sometimes the whole map disappears to reveal the page background. (At least the map returns to normal when the text input area loses focus.) But why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up). Simply had to add

```
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
</activity>
```

to AndroidManifest.xml.