# Related to toolbar,multiple screens layout etc

Tags: android, android-layout

Actually I'm working on an Android application and we want to run our app only on devices and tablets(All screen sizes).....
so please clarify my below questions

**1.** the question is I know that for supporting different screens, I have to create a different layout xml ,but I think Android Studio provide the direct shortcut to create a xml for the desired screens(check image-1...some where highlight portion)

[image]
 **2.** I installed some plugin(Batch Drawable import) by this plugin I scaled my image(Check image-2) in **six** format, so should I keep all six format of image or some...because I am targeting only **devices and Tablets**
[image]
 **3.** In my Activity there are some Edittext at bottom of the screen and when I enter some thing into the Edittext, then my Toolbar moves upwards(out of the screen)....so should I use scrollView or not for avoiding this ?

**NOTE:1** I already tried this  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"`

Edit: xml for the Thrid Question:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:id="@+id/logo1"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar1"
    />
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="0dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/textViewBackground"
    android:layout_below="@+id/logo1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardView">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp">
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/phone_icon"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/email_icon"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/symbol"
            android:id="@+id/symbol"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/symbol"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

            >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_name_email"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:paddingBottom="25dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/symbol"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
                android:hint="Email Address"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>




    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="0dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/textViewBackground"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardView1">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp">
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/password_icon"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/password_icon"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/symbol"
            android:id="@+id/symbol2"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_name2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/symbol2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

            >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_name_password"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:paddingBottom="25dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/symbol"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>




    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="0dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/textViewBackground"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cardView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardView2">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp">
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/otp_icon"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/confirm_password_icon"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/symbol"
            android:id="@+id/symbol3"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_name3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/symbol3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

            >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_name_confirm_password"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:paddingBottom="25dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/symbol"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
                android:hint="Confirm Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
<Button

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cardView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/signup_button"
    android:id="@+id/signup_button" />
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: your third problem is due to adjust pan. If you want that then use scrollview else remove it.

Comment: if i use scrollview than my toolbar will be fixed?

Comment: no, but on scroll you can see your toolbar

Comment: bt i want to fix my toolbar postion so is der any way?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up and you should use a proper title for your question. Your current title doesn't give any idea about your problem

Comment: i already tried it bt it's no work for me

Answer (score 1):

**Answer of Question 1:**

Yes, you do have to create a different layout for each device screen. Recommended way is create the following folders:

`layout` for normal mobile devices (6" and below)

`layout-sw600dp` for 7" Tablets

`layout-sw720dp` for 8" Tablets and above

***The highlighted portion just shows the preview of your layout on different screens under different API levels.***

**Answer of Question 2:**

Yes, you do need all the images. The images will scale as per the device display. The tablets will use `xxhdpi` and so on. You can however use a single vector graphic, if possible. The Android system will take of the scaling itself.

**Answer of Question 3:**

Please paste the xml code and screenshots along with the question.

Comment: The highlighted portion can actually create layout for different screen sizes

Comment: @VivekMishra, Can you please tell us how to do that?

Comment: @DhirenParmar in layout editor, option to right of language icon will give you option to do that

Comment: @VivekMishra .. It creates same same xml files inside large, xlarge folders. It doesnt create anything responsive. It's same as creating a layout-xlarge folder and pasting layout files inside it.

Comment: @techDigi If you wanna create a single layout that scales itself as per the screen size, use ConstraintLayout (Android Studio 2.2 and above)