# The layout changes when the soft keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I have two `linearlayout` one is below the other as below:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/reg_imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/z"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/reg_app_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_title"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/req_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/request_number"
            android:inputType="number" />
```

Here is the picture of the layout:

[image: before the soft keyboard]

when the keyboard shows, the layout get missed up:

[image: when the keyboard shows]

What is causing this issue?

NOTE: I have `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"` line in the .xml file that holds the `EditText` that requires the (Request number)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How do I prevent the soft keyboard from pushing my view up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in manifest for this activity put

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

Comment: Actually he probably wants adjustPan.  His problem seems to be with a resize.