# How To Prevent Android Toolbar moves up when keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-toolbar

I Want to Prevent app bar pushing up When Edittext Clicks Please help me to prevent Appbar scrolling and i added android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" and adjustpan but not worked please help me.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:id="@+id/act"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.admin.easydart.View.Dart">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#016ba9"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/actS"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"


                android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: use scrollview height as a wrap_content

Comment: use this
<activity
   ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> 
</activity>

Comment: have you use Fullscreen theme in activity in manifests ? it should be effect to android:windowSoftInputMode.

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
       
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
this is my theme

Answer (score 3):

set in onCreate method of your activity class:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)
to your activity inside your manifest file

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
    android:theme="@style/StoreSetting" />
```

Comment: some documentation would be nice

Comment: i want only Appbar prevent.by using of this keybord appears on the edittext

Answer (score 0):

use this inside your activity tag

```
 <activity
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

for more reference look [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up)