# Keyboard moves item of the Activity in Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

### **EDIT:** Looks like [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7509285/6683139) is the main problem here

In my application's **MainActivity** I have a **custom bottom navigation** which is a horizontal recyclerview. I have an access to this recyclerview in all of my Fragments for navigation. The thing is when I focus on an **edittext inside my fragment**, soft input method moves that recyclerview up, how can I force the screen to pan just for the items in my Fragment's layout.

[![here is my fragment with activity's bottom navigation][2]][2]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

I tried to put `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` and then `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` to my activity in my Manifest.

then I tried to do those programatically **inside my Activity**.

then I tried to do the same **inside my Fragment** this time, nothing helped. Literally no way to make the keyboard ignore the activity.

Main Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d9d5ce"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_background"
        android:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    </FrameLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/accent"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical|horizontal"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="60dp"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager">


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit: I already tried possible solutions like `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` the problem is when the edittext inside fragment gain focus, Recyclerview in my activity moves up and I lost pan

**FYI: my fragment's root layout is `ScrollView`**

Comment: Post the layout of main Activity

Comment: @Redman posted see edit

Comment: use `LinearLayout` as parent and check once

Comment: what do you exactly want your layout to behave ?

Comment: @SantanuSur his bottom bar is coming on top of his keyboard

Comment: i got that .. @Redman this aint fixable... !! it will move up over the fragment no matter what !! he has to explain what would he like as an alternative !!

Comment: @SantanuSur every thing is fixable in android ,we just need little tweak/hack

Comment: you mean how would it look ? keyboard over the background?? hiding the background ? @Redman *blocking* the user to switch between the nav items ?

Comment: @Redman changing it to LinearLayout completely removes the Recyclerview

Comment: @SantanuSur I just want user NOT TO SEE nav bar when the keyboard is open that's it

Comment: @EgeKuzubasioglu use frameLayout height 0dp and its weight as 1

Comment: @Redman No luck still moves up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How do I prevent the soft keyboard from pushing my view up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up)

Comment: @Micer already tried those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by observing the keyboard and set visibility of the nav bar. here is the full solution:

https://medium.com/@egek92/beaware-of-android-bug-5497-for-your-own-sake-19cf76abb7e5

Answer (score 0):

Wrap up a `ScrollView` (as **RootLayout** ) above the `RelativeLayout` and the

*View would adjust and move up accordingly* !!

```
<ScrollView
  android:width="match_parent"
  android:height="match_parent"
  ....
  .... >
     <RelativeLayout
       .....
       .....
```

**Edit:-**

If you want to hide a view after the keyboard opens , you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216749/softkeyboard-open-and-close-listener-in-an-activity-in-android/25680383).

Comment: `adjust and move up accordingly` I don't want to make it move up

Comment: do you want to hide a view behind the keyboard when it opens ?? @EgeKuzubasioglu

Comment: yes! I want to hide the recyclerview(my custom bottom navigation) in my activity and just show the framelayout of my fragment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide  keyboard, you can try this.

```
 public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
            (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(
                    Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
            activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
  }
```