# Softkeypad pushing the footer view

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-keypad

I tried everyhing in this [Android: How do I prevent the soft keyboard from pushing my view up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up/55475832#55475832)

But none of them not worked for me
Here is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:isScrollContainer="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

      <....Widgets>

     </LinearLayout>
     </scrollview>

     <com.mypackage.activities.Footer
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/footerHeight"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As well as in Manifest file used adjustResize,adjsutPan,adjustNothing

[image]

Comment: It would be easier with pictures, so we knew exactly what you're seeing, and what you want.  Assuming you want the keyboard to come up over the footer, you need to be in adjustPan mode.

Comment: If you want to not let the softkeypad to push the footer view up then you should use `adjustnothing` with a vscrollview` as root layout.

Comment: @GabeSechan with adjustPan footer is getting pushed but scrollview not working

Comment: @AbidKhan if I make scrollview as root view then footer also gets scrolled, but i don't want footer to be scrolled

Comment: @GabeSechan typo *footer not getting pushed

Answer (score 0):

Make `ScrollView` as root layout which will also contain your footer layout. Inside `Manifest` file use `adjustNothing` for `windowsoftinputmode`.

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:isScrollContainer="false">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

      <....Widgets>

     </LinearLayout>

     <com.mypackage.activities.Footer
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/footerHeight"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</scrollview>
```