# How to force the soft input to overlap bottom-anchored View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, appcompatdialogfragment

**TL;DR**: *soft keyboard should overlap a bottom-anchored view instead of pushing it up. [Gitlab link](https://gitlab.com/Droidman/soft-keyboard-issue-demo) for an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)*.

Summary:

I have an `AppCompatDialogFragment` (androidx) which appears *fullscreen* on phones and has *fixed dimensions* on tablets (using `dialog?.window?.setLayout(width, height)` in case this matters). The dialog's layout has some content placed in a `ScrollView` and a button-like layout anchored at the bottom (complete XML structure see below).

Side note: the superclass of the `AppCompatDialogFragment` in question calls `setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN)`on its `Window`.

The problem:

When the soft keyboard appears as a result of some text input receiving focus, it pushes the complete layout up, including the bottom-anchored view that I want overlapped by the soft keyboard. For some reason, **the issue only affects phones**, on tablets the soft keyboard correctly overlaps everything including the bottom-anchored view without any additional adjustments or flags.

What I have tried (without any success):

- setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` (tried other flags "just in case" as well) for the `Activity` in question, also tried to apply them in code
- setting `android:isScrollContainer="false"` on the `ScrollView` and its parent
- combinations of the above
- looking for similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up) and confirming the proposed solutions didn't work

Here's the layout in question (*note: I omitted many unrelated attributes to keep the snippet reasonably sized; everything is positioned vertically matching the elements' order. The `<include>` elements contain the text inputs*):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar         
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include
                layout="@layout/some_layout_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <include
                layout="@layout/some_layout_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

  <!-- I want this one to be overlapped by the soft input, but it's just pushed up -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/divider"
            android:background="@color/dark_grey" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/some_dimen"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="@string/text" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The question: **how do I force the soft keyboard to overlap the layout anchored at the bottom on all devices?**

Please comment if you need any additional details.

EDIT: here's a minimal demo app that reproduces the issue: https://gitlab.com/Droidman/soft-keyboard-issue-demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following line to `onCreateView()` of `DemoDialog`:

`dialog.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING)`

*It is important to apply this change to the window of the dialog and not to the window of the activity.*

With this in place, this is what I see on an Nexus 6 emulator running API 29 using your MCVE:

[image]

You may need to work with the placement a little, but this should help.

---

Let's look under the hood a little. For a phone and a tablet, the soft input mode is zero in `onCreateView()`. This value corresponds to [SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_UNSPECIFIED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_UNSPECIFIED).  The documentation for [SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN) explains what happens when the soft input mode is unspecified (emphasis is mine.)

> Adjustment option for *softInputMode* : set to have a window pan when an input method is shown, so it doesn't need to deal with resizing but just panned by the framework to ensure the current input focus is visible. This can *not* be combined with SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE ; **if neither of these are set, then the system will try to pick one or the other depending on the contents of the window**.

Looking at the value of the soft input mode in `onStart()` (`dialog?.window?.attributes?.softInputMode`) shows the value selected by the system for the phone is [SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE) and the value selected for the tablet is [SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN). This explains the difference that is seen between phones and tablets.

So,  always setting the soft input mode to `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN` looks like the best solution although `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING` also works and may be preferable for certain layouts.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, it works. I guess my obvious mistake was that I tried to set the `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING` (and others) at the Activity level, either via Manifest of code, disregarding the fact that I actually needed to apply them to the *dialog's window* instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your class inside the  tags in the AndroidManifest in your Class:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work, the layout at the bottom is still pushed above the soft input. "state hidden" was already being set in code, I have updated the question to reflect this though I doubt it matters much.

Comment: Can you share the code? So i can check the issue properly

Comment: I created a simple demo app which demonstrates the issue https://gitlab.com/Droidman/soft-keyboard-issue-demo  as you can see  in the manifest your suggestion is already applied